# Spring: JDBCTemplate doesn't get injected correctly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, dependency-injection

Seems like I've hit other dead end in my Spring project, and I'm hoping someone here can help me.

My project structure is as follows: [Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aat0y.png)

My code:

**BookController**

```
@Controller
public class BookController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getBookData(Book book, ModelMap model) {
        model.put("data", book.getBooks());
        return "BookView";
    }
}
```

**Book**

```
@Component
public class Book {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String isbn;

    public Book() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public Book(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public ModelMap getBooks() {
        ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Books";
        model.put("data", jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql));
        return model;
    }
}
```

**AppConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"models", "controllers"})
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onlinelibrary");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

And I'm getting a null pointer exception when trying to access jdbcTemplate in the Book getBooks() method. It's esentially like the dependency injecting isn't working at all.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You don't need the default constructor in the `Book` class, neither the `@Autowired` annotation on the other constructor. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection) for more details. Also, generally speaking, constructor injection is better. And I'm not sure you need `@ComponentScan` annotation.

Comment: I do need the default constructor. If I delete it, in execution I get a exception due no default constructor found.

In any case, I deleted the `@Autowired` from the Constructor, but I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to access `jdbcTemplate` in `Book getBooks()` method.
Any ideas?

PS: I edited the main topic accordingly.

Comment: Because you are injecting `Book` as a method parameter which makes it not a spring managed bean. It should be a instance level property. Also you are using Spring Boot which already creates a `DataSource` and `JdbcTemplate`, enables web en does component scanning so remove the `AppConfig` class.

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question] over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Please use @Autowired in Book, so that Spring can inject the actual Object.

```
@Component
public class Book {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Putting @Autowired before `public class Book` doesn't make sense. I don't want to inject that, i just want it to be a bean (which is done with @Component).

Comment: Yes Putting JDBCTemplate in Book doesn't make any sense. create another DAO mark it as repository and use JDBCTemplate over there. Please see my new Answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Repository
public class BookDAO {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Book> findAllBooks(){

        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM Books",new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Book.class)); //BeanPropertyRowMapper can be used when propertyname canbe derived from column name
    }
}

public class Book implement Serializable{
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String isbn;

    public Book() {

    }
    //all getter setter
}
```